# Attitude quaternion from 2 vector measurements

Tags: vectors, rotational-kinematics, rotation, geometry, complex-numbers

I am using a method proposed by R. G. Reynolds to estimate attitude based on two vector measurements, taken from: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19990052720.pdf

Suppose we measure 2 unit vectors $b_{1}$ and $b_{2}$ in the body frame, and we know the components in the inertial frame are $r_{1}$ and $r_{2}$. The attitude quaternion can be calculated:

$$ c = |(b_{1} - r_{1}) \times (b_{2} - r_{2})|^2 + ((b_{1} + r_{1})\cdot (b_{2} - r_{2}))^2$$

$$q = \frac{1}{\sqrt{c}} [b_{2} \cdot r_{1} - b_{1} \cdot r_{2}, (b_{1} - r_{1}) \times (b_{2} - r_{2})] $$

Where $c$ is a normalisation factor and $q$ is in the form $[w, \vec{v}]$.

I've been trying this method out and it works half the time, but occasionally all the elements of the quaternion are their negative. Is there a way around this problem?

I know there is also a singularity problem when the two vectors are parallel but I don't think this is the problem?